# chrome.webRequest API Blacklist

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest

Where can I find in Chromium Code Source the blacklist regarding the webRequest API?

> The webRequest API only exposes requests that the extension has
>   permission to see, given its host permissions. Moreover, only the
>   following schemes are accessible: http://, https://, ftp://, file://,
>   or chrome-extension://. In addition, even certain requests with URLs
>   using one of the above schemes are hidden, e.g.,
>   chrome-extension://other_extension_id where other_extension_id is not
>   the ID of the extension to handle the request,
>   https://www.google.com/chrome, and others (this list is not complete).

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#life_cycle_footnote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Implementation: [chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/web_request/web_request_permissions.cc](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/web_request/web_request_permissions.cc)
2. Unit tests: [chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/web_request/web_request_permissions_unittest.cc](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/web_request/web_request_permissions_unittest.cc)

The following URLs are blacklisted (patterns can be derived from the source code and/or unit tests):

```
      "http://clients2.google.com",
      "http://clients22.google.com",
      "https://clients2.google.com",
      "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
      "https://clients.google.com",
      "https://test.clients.google.com",
      "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
      "http://www.gstatic.com/chrome/extensions/blacklist",
      "https://www.gstatic.com/chrome/extensions/blacklist",
      "notregisteredscheme://www.foobar.com"
```

Comment: Interestingly, https://www.google.com/chrome is not mentioned in the source code. This URL redirects to https://www.google.com/intl/nl/chrome/browser/, which *can* be blocked (test case: http://pastebin.com/11yWxaiZ). Furthermore, not all of the URLs in the unit test are immune to my demo, which could indicate that the enforcement of the blacklist is not waterproof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like declarativeWebRequest API also uses web_request_permissions.